# Domain name is parked.

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting

I am new to website building thing and I bought a domain called "view-unlimited". It's been 2-4 days since I got the domain and I also got hosting service from a different site. I also registered the domain name in the hosting site that I got but every time when I try to access my website, it shows "This site is parked with DreamHost
The DreamHost customer who owns this domain has parked their website.
If you are the owner of this domain, you'll find your login information contained within the emails sent to you when your account was activated. Once logged in you'll be able to change your website's hosting option under the Manage Domain section of your Web Panel."

I really can't get to the problem and I will really appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In website development, you first need to register a domain name and get yourself the web space to host your website. After domain registration, the domain registrar will point the DNS of your site over some default name server. You need to change  the default DNS to start logging in your cpanel from the web space provider.
The DNS will be provided by the web space provider.

After you register for web hosting, you will get an email with following information.
New Account Info

+===================================

| Domain: yourdomain.com
| Ip: 108.163.250.186 (n)
| HasCgi: y
| UserName: username
| PassWord: password
| CpanelMod: x3
| HomeRoot: /home
| Quota: 1000 Meg
**| NameServer1: ns1.host_name.com
| NameServer2: ns2.host_name.com**
| NameServer3: 
| NameServer4: 
| Contact Email: mail.abc@xxx.com
| Package: xxx
| Feature List: default
| Language: en

Just change the nameservers provided by the web host. Then login using your username and password on yoursite.com/cpanel.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually wasn't fully hosting it. I got the prob later. Thanks anyways ..:)